# Image Colorization - How to equalize shape of features of image and output from a picture

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I am making a project ML based image colorization as example-based. I have a colorful image as source. I am getting B G R values from it and I am generating output (y).

For example, if a picture is 320x461, I have 320*461 = 147520 output with 3 dimension that B G R. So, I have an output with shape of (147520,3). Then, I am changing that picture to grayscale. After that I am extracting features from that image.

My problem is starting here. If I extract features with hog or orb, the extracted features size does not match input size and I could not fit a model with those values.

For example, if I used hog that `fd = hog(img_target, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(4, 4), cells_per_block=(1, 1))` the shape of fd is 82800.

On the other hand, if I used features as greyscale image that

```
features = np.reshape(img_target, (img_target.shape[0]*img_target.shape[1]))
features = features.reshape(-1,1)
```

it is giving me same shape as y.

After that I am fitting a model with KNN with X as features variable and y as B,G,R values.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn_clf.fit(features,y)
```

Then, I have an image that similar to source image (same place different angle) and I am extracting features from it too and making prediction to B,G,R values.

```
features_test = np.reshape(img_test, (img_test.shape[0]*img_test.shape[1]))
features_test = features_test.reshape(-1,1)

y_predict = knn_clf.predict(features_test)
```

Then, I am going to create an image from predicted B,G,R values but the output that colorized image by model is not good enough.

```
height,width = img_test.shape
data = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

tmp = 0
for i in range(height):
    for k in range(width):
        data[i,k] = [y_predict[tmp][0], y_predict[tmp][1], y_predict[tmp][2]]
        tmp +=1
```

Example;

[This is my source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTUiz.png)

[And this is my target image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ3bR.png)

[This is colorful image after prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuaqV.png)

What should I do?